# Ubuntu cannot mount logic wireless keyboard and mouse automatically

Tags: logitech-unifying, wireless-keyboards

I want to use a KVM hub(keyboard/mouse switch) to share logic wireless keyboard(K270) and mouse(M330), between two PCs(Win10 and Ubuntu16.04). Everything works fine with Win10 OS, but when switch to Ubuntu16.04, both keyboard and mouse not work, until plugin the receiver again. I checked on Ubuntu16.04, lsusb could detect the receiver and KVM hub normally as below:

```
Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver 
Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
```

But there is no input device when checking with command "cat /proc/bus/input/devices".
Where they should appear when they work fine.
kmsg as below when switching to Ubuntu16.04.

```
<6>[606693.847598] usb 1-12: new high-speed USB device number 63 using xhci_hcd
<6>[606693.995731] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=1a40, idProduct=0101
<6>[606693.995738] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
<6>[606693.995742] usb 1-12: Product: USB 2.0 Hub
<6>[606693.996306] hub 1-12:1.0: USB hub found
<6>[606693.996340] hub 1-12:1.0: 4 ports detected
<6>[606694.403572] usb 1-12.1: new full-speed USB device number 64 using xhci_hcd
```

It looks like the Ubuntu16.04 didn't mount keyboard and mouse when detect the receiver. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: I also use a KVM switch with Ubuntu. I do not think they work well with wireless devices. Have you tried to get information form the maker of the switch. I do not think this is a Ubuntu problem, BTW 16.04 is EOL in April and all support for it will end. Time to think about an upgrade?

Comment: Yes, the update should be on schedule. Which Ubuntu OS are you using?  I check kmsg on Ubuntu16.04, it looks like the  OS detected wireless key board and mouse, but disappear after that.